# Content not shown in site after publishing

Tags: sitecore-client, publishing, caching

Sitecore 10.0.1
Published changes of one particular component is not showing up in site.
The content is there in web db. And cache is also cleared and no error logs.
Workflow of the item is also compelted. But strangely the component is not reflecting on live site

Answer (score 0):

First try to run page in preview mode or experience editor mode. If you are able
to see component there it means rendering is not published. Then go to Web Db and Check datasource and component showing in item's presentation details or not.

You can select Web database by bottom right button as shown in below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Its coming in preview and Experience editor mode. Datasource and component is also showing in presentation details

Comment: Did you check Datasource and component is also showing in presentation details in Web database ?

Comment: Yes i checked. Datasource and component is also showing in presentation details in Web database.

Comment: Can you please share screenshots of presentation details of item from Web DB and make sure templates related to this component item is published.

Comment: Cannot share screenshots due to security issue. But templates also published. Earlier once this issue happened, I simply republished the item and it worked. But this time that also is not working

Comment: try with clear cache using sitecoreinstance/siteore/admin/cache.aspx

Comment: I cleared cache but not working

Comment: If you are on local environment then you can just do full site publish

Comment: No, it is working in my local environment. This is in higher environment

Comment: try to do a small change in other component on same item and then check it is reflecting there or not

Comment: if i craete a new component it comes. It is an article component and it is supposed to be clicked and taken to detail page. This detail page works in cm server but gives 404 in cd

Comment: if you are using CM and CD environments then please make sure code is deployed on CD environments properly.